# sub model in sub view binding c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the folowing main model :

```
public class PersonalDetailContainerViewModel {

    public AprobacionViewModel aprobacionPersonal { get; set; }
    public AprobacionViewModel aprobacionMinera { get; set; }

public PersonalDetailContainerViewModel() {
        aprobacionPersonal = new AprobacionViewModel();
        aprobacionMinera = new AprobacionViewModel();
    }
}
```

the sub model :

```
public class AprobacionViewModel {

    [DisplayName("Observación")]
    public string observation { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Responsable")]
    public string responsable { get; set; }
    [UIHint("DropDownList")]
    [DisplayName("Estado")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListEstado { get; set; }

    public AprobacionViewModel() {
        ListEstado = CommonService.createDropDownListEstado();
    }

}
```

the main view :

```
@model PersonalDetailContainerViewModel

@Html.Partial("Aprobacion", Model.aprobacionPersonal)
@Html.Partial("Aprobacion", Model.aprobacionMinera)
```

and ... the detail view :

```
@model AprobacionViewModel
<fieldset>
    <legend>Aprobación / Rechazo</legend>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListEstado, null)<br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.observation, null)<br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.responsable, new { disabled = "disabled" })

</fieldset>
```

My question, in the binding i receive always a null value for the fields of AprobacionViewModel:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(PersonalDetailContainerViewModel model){

    model.aprobacionPersonal.observation //NULL ??
}
```

it's possible to use a sub model in a sub view without custom modelbinder ?

ps: Darin Dimitrov is my heroe :)) i want a fan page just for click "i like it !"
Darin vous êtes mon héros !! ou est votre page facebook pour les fans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.Partial` does not respect model hierachy when rendering elements, so the form elements will not be named appropriately and thus not model bound.

Use `@Html.EditorFor` instead:

```
@model PersonalDetailContainerViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.aprobacionPersonal)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.aprobacionMinera)
```

Use `Html.Partial` for rendering HTML content/layouts, etc - not things as part of the form.